# magento customer register add observer

Tags: customer, register

i am new to magento i want to add observer to magento customer register , where i check reference code if code not valid do not register customer.

what have i do override customer registration ?..

what observer have i write for it any guide or refernce

Answer (score 1):

There are several options.

1. You may rewrite controller `app\code\core\Mage\Customer\controllers\AccountController.php` and update method `createPostAction`
2. You may rewrite customer form model `app\code\core\Mage\Customer\Model\Form.php`
   and update the `validateData` method.
3. You may observer `customer_save_before` event, and, in case of new customer and front-end area, throw an exception.